# git push hang and bad file descriptor

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

First of all I must say that this problem occurs only on one of my repositories.
I want to push.
Takes very long and after following line

```
Writing objects: 100% (823/823), 73.56 MiB | 34.07 MiB/s, done.
```

gets stuck.
I increased buffer by

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "32m"
```

Then it became faster but the main problem persists.

A hint I got using

```
strace -efile -f git push
```

The result is

```
Writing objects: 100% (823/823), 73.56 MiB | 34.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 823 (delta 522), reused 752 (delta 454), pack-reused 0
[pid  2380] newfstatat(1, "", 0x7ffea1c08270, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid  2380] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid  2375] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=2380, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=70 /* 0.70 s */, si_stime=20 /* 0.20 s */}
```

Still I dont know what to do here...

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: You better report this to the [Git mailing list](https://git-scm.com/community). Provide a reproduction recipe if possible. If the repository is publically accessible, mention its location.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by accident.
I just tried again and gave git lot of time.
Quickly the following line was reached:

```
Total 857 (delta 539), reused 749 (delta 454), pack-reused 0
```

Then long pause and then the following appeared:

```
remote: resolving deltas: 100% (539/539), completed with 37 local objects. 
remote: warning: see https://gh.io/lfs for more information. 
remote: warning: File xxxxx/xxxx.pdf ... files size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage... 
...
```

And that was the reason: I added a very large file.
I find git's treatment of the problem very bad.
I installed LFS, now all ok.

Comment: "I find git's treatment of the problem very bad." It has nothing to do with Git. Git was just doing what you told it to do. The objection comes from Github. The file had to arrive there and unpack before Github could know about it and wave it off.

Comment: @matt: could you explain? Is then `Total... pack-reused 0` the last message from git, the rest is github? 
Or take it the other way round: `remote: ` signifies message from github?

Comment: "remote:  signifies message from github" It signifies a message *from the remote.* In your case that's Github. Git has no objection to large files; Github does. See https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github

Comment: @matt: very good hint! So solution LFS is dealing on git side with github restriction. 
Not really clear to me why then github fails so ungracefully... No message just seemingly no reaction.

Comment: LFS is a Github thing too. Git knows nothing about it.

Comment: oh, not so obvious https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/. 
Still seems a subcommand of git. 
But, anyway, works.

Comment: "Still seems a subcommand of git" GitHub is not Git. LFS is not Git. Pull requests are not Git. (It is true that git-lfs is "injected" in such a way that you can say `git lfs` at the command line, but _you_ could do exactly the same thing; you could easily create a custom tool yourself such as `git-blahblah` so that you could say `git blahblah` at the command line.)